# How determine the rolling windows, minimum observation, and maximum lags using AMIM model?

Tags: r, statistics, quantitative-finance

**How to determine rolling windows, minimum observations, and maximum lags in AMIM model? Given that the data consists of daily data points totalling around 2400.**

Firstly, I've encountered empty results after running the AMIM model in R Studio. Even though the coding and data format are exactly the same as the existing CRAN package.

Empty result after running the AMIM model:

[image]

Secondly, after trying different parameters like rolling windows, minimum observations, and maximum lags, the results still don't show up, but there's an increase in the percentage of the process. This percentage keeps going up when I increase the rolling windows closer to the number of data points for each asset class, with the same minimum observations and maximum lags. However, this doesn't result in the AMIM analysis table or it remains empty. This doesn't happen in the example of the AMIM Package in CRAN. The percentage reaches 100% when using the same coding and data with the same format and content.

Here are the results of running the code with parameters and data from the example in the AMIM Package in CRAN.

Successful/expected result:

[image]

And here are the results of running the code with parameters and research data: there are no results for AMIM calculations, and the percentage only goes up to 25% by changing the rolling windows.

My empty and percentage using the same coding and data format:

[image]

The expectation is my result % is 100% and the output table from running the AMIM model is not empty.